# Get rid of Left space from UITableView

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I have searched everywhere but cannot find answer to this question.

In my `UITableView`'s cells, there is empty space on the left side. How do I get rid of it?

This is how I initiated the `UITableView` object:

```
listTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, _tableWidth, _tableheight) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

[image: table view]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
listTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I add subview to UITableViewCell, not setting labelText.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to govern the inset of that *textLabel* and the separator
you need to subclass UITableViewCell

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@end
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = self.textLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 5;
    self.textLabel.frame = frame;

    // available only from iOS7
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
}

@end
```